# Linking github repository with my Amazon EC2 Instances AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

I am new to github and AWS. I want to deploy my code directly from my github repository (a simple 'hello world' html page), and onto my EC2 instance. I was following this tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ-tutorial.html However on step 4 I am struggling.

It says after 'launched the instance and verified the AWS CodeDeploy agent is running, go to the next step'.

But, how do I verify AWS CodeDeploy Agent is running? It says to follow this link, however i am lost with it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html#how-to-run-agent-install-windows (windows server)

Where do i put these commands in and where? And do I need the AWS SDK first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the code deploy agent is running from the command

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

If the command returns an error, the AWS CodeDeploy agent is not installed. Install it as described in [To install, uninstall, or reinstall the AWS CodeDeploy agent for Amazon Linux or RHEL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html#how-to-run-agent-install-linux)

If the AWS CodeDeploy agent is installed and running, you should see a message like `The AWS CodeDeploy agent is running.`

If you see a message like error: `No AWS CodeDeploy agent running`, start the service and run the following two commands, one at a time:

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent start
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html if you want info for another os type

Comment: Do I need to SHH into my instance first before I can do this? Thanks

Comment: yes _to verify if the agent is running_ you would need to SSH into the instance and run the sudo command from bash